# how to rewrite root to sub but have access to /? links?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my root

> www.domain.com

to

> www.domain.com/sub

I can do it with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /sub [L]
```

but what is the problem?
with this code, some links like

> www.domain.com/?example

wont work and will be redirected to:

> www.domain.com/sub/?example

so, how can I rewrite root to sub while I have access to

> www.domain.com/?example

Comment: Well, that's what happens if you are rewriting your base url!

Comment: Also rewrite `/?` (using something like `RewriteRule ^\? - [L]`)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to rewrite the link, but only in cases without query string.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteRule ^$ /sub [L]
```